# Triple boot Windows 7, 8 and Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: dual-boot

I have got a new computer and I want to install Windows 7, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 on it, In which order should I install them?? I tried installing Windows 7 first then Windows 8 and finally Ubuntu 13.04 but it shows only Windows 7, 8 during boot. Can anyone please provide exact steps to be followed while installing.

Answer (score 2):

The order you used is correct. First install all Windows versions you like, from the oldest to the newest. This will ensure that all of them are automatically added to the Windows Bootloader. Then install other operating systems. If you start with operating systems other than Windows, their Bootloader will be deleted during Windows installation.

The two most likely reasons that you can't boot Ubuntu are:

- If your computer is using UEFI (nearly all new computers do), you have to install all operating systems with the same firmware interface: UEFI or BIOS. If your computer has UEFI, read the [UEFI help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) page.
- You might have installed the Ubuntu bootloader to a different hard drive than the one, the computer boots from. If you think this might be the case, have a look at [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Usually the bootloader has to be installed directly to the first hard drive, sda. If you haven't been asked during installation, where to install the bootloader, it should have been installed to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download  `Boot-Repair disk`,
2.burn the iso file to dvd or usb
3.Boot it
4.click Recommended Repair. Done.